# Names in kesuba and gittin

Tags: halacha, names, divorce, ketubah

The name a person is given at birth has no real relevance, it all depends on what he is called at the moment. One can change ones name as often as one likes (but not one's fathers). Today when women are only called by their English names and only sign their English names their Hebrew name given at birth has absolutely no relevance whatsoever. (Men at least have aliyot to remind them). 
Is a kesuba or get kosher if a woman uses her hebrew name?

Comment: The reason I mention the fathers name is because the Chasam Sofer has a problem with someone who all his life had never known the correct name of his father until he had to give a get. So to use the incorrect one with which he had had aliyot he can't, and to use the correct one he can't, because then people would think he was not the husband of the wife since he had always been called up by another (fathers' name).

Comment: "Today when women are only called by their English names and only sign their English names": in some circles, I guess.

Comment: Why would it matter on a Kesuba; a legal document that either stands up in Bet Din or doesn't. If you can prove you are "wrong-name" then who cares? I do understand the concern about the Get - where getting the names right is crucial.

Comment: @Danny Schoemann Thank you. There are quite a few points here many of which I am not yet sure of. There in an arguement if a written kesuba since it is meant to be kept for a long time does that mean the names have not been abandoned. Is there a difference between the husband and the wife who keeps the kesuba. Would one have to make a new kesuba if the name is abandoned, that means when it existed at the time of the marriage.

Comment: @Danny Schoemann The name on the kesuba has to be spelled  correctly for the simple reason because when it comes to a get one uses the same spelling and takes it from there. According to this one should be using all ones names like in a get. There is a very large 'variety' of names each with its own peculiarities and special dinim of how they should be written and in which order. I would like to know why they are not also written in the kesuba. Of course if they change a new kesuba may be necessary.

Comment: There are what are called Hebrew names or even non Hebrew like Esther which are classified as Hebrew names. There are nick names, some which have a 'shaichos' to the original and some which dont. There are names which are given or added when a person is ill. There are names which people are called by, which people sign themselves and which one is given an alyah with. All these can differ although they are all in the present. One can also be called different names in different places. I shall post a page here of them.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7797&st=&pgnum=9&hilite=     http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7797&st=&pgnum=10         http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7797&st=&pgnum=11

Comment: @preferred: What is your source for this assertion? "The name on the kesuba has to be spelled correctly for the simple reason because when it comes to a get one uses the same spelling and takes it from there." - Just curious.

Comment: http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1600&st=&pgnum=244 as can be seen this question was asked to the minchas yitschok

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7797&st=&pgnum=110&hilite= seems to answer the question. Mainly that one has to 'actively' abandon a name before it is called abandoned, by not using it where it should be used or by having an intention not to use it again.

Comment: Thnanks, @preferred - I'm not sure you were answering my question, but from my reading of http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1600&st=&pgnum=244 it says that even though it may be the correct thing to do, the Minhag is not to be overly careful about the names.

Comment: @Danny Schoemann Your question was to provide the source which  I gave as the nachlas shiva.

Comment: @preferred - right, I forgot that. יישר כוחך.